# Empty Guid string displays as 0 in angular/typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I would like to understand why the following behavior happens.

Take a look at my Stackblitz example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-veevdq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

I need the "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" empty guid, to stay in the same format, but for some reason, Typescript changes it to a value 0.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Change ```[value] = "value="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"```  to ```value="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"```.. Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nmdws7

Answer (score 3):

Fixed it with this.

```
[value]="'00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'"
```

So it is now a string.